# why bootstrap returns empty and values for standard deviation and CI and others are missing

Tags: stata, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Stata `bootstrap` command to estimate the sd of the median of the `hours` variable from the nlsw88 dataset.

I can't get the answer but when I changed the variable in my code from `hours` to `wage` it works. The only difference between these two variables is that `hours` is integer while `wage` has decimals. I even changed the storage type of `hours` from `byte` to `float` but nothing changed.

```
sysuse nlsw88
bootstrap r(p50),  nodots: summarize hours , detail
```

Comment: Storage type and whether the variable is integer are not key here, but the flatness of the distribution in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bootstrapping to estimate the median (`p50`), but in practice there is no variance in the median.

Not sure exactly how `bootstrap` works, but you are not setting a sample size and 48.75% of the observations has the value 40 which is also close to the mean. All of this makes it very likely that the medians in all samples are 40 and that there therefore is no variance between the samples.

You must pick a very small sample size to be likely to get any variance in the median between the randomly drawn samples. For example, if you only sample 5 observations each bootstrap round.

```
sysuse nlsw88
bootstrap r(p50) , size(5) nodots: summarize hours , detail
```

This might explain why you are getting missing values (which is your question), but it does not answer what you should do instead. Ask yourself if you really meant to use the median? Or if bootstrap is the right method to use here?

Comment: (+1) OP: This is the answer. Plus look at e.g. `quantile hours` to see the distribution in detail. Always look at the data, especially if results are puzzling.